# Creating too many topics in Azure Service bus via BICEP file

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-bicep

I have a list of 100+ topics that I pass into a bicep file below.

```
param serviceBusName string
param topics array
param location string = resourceGroup().location

resource serviceBus_resource  'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces@2021-11-01' = {
  name: serviceBusName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Premium'
    tier: 'Premium'
    capacity: 1
  }
}

resource serviceBus_topics 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics@2021-11-01' = [for item in topics: {
  name: '${serviceBusName}/${item.n}'
  dependsOn: [
    serviceBus_resource
  ]
}]
```

When I tried to add another topic, I get the following error on my Azure Devops pipeline:

**This results in an error "##[warning]Environment variable 'TOPICSTOCREATE' exceeds the maximum supported length. Environment variable length: 32770 , Maximum supported length: 32766"**

I have tried to break down the  for loop

e.g.

```
param topicsCount = length(topics)
[for i in range(0, itemCount): {
                        param subsetTopics = take(skip(topics, i), 10)
                        resource serviceBus_topics 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics@2021-11-01' = [for item in subsetTopics: {
                          name: '${serviceBusName}/${item.n}'
                        }]
                        i = i + 10
}]
```

and similar things, but it looks like nested loops are not possible in bicep? Is there a way  around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sounds like you just want to batch the resource creation, in which case you can just use the [batchSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/loops#deploy-in-batches) decorator on the resource.

```
@batchSize(10)
resource serviceBus_topics 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics@2021-11-01' = [for item in topics: {
  name: '${serviceBusName}/${item.n}'
  dependsOn: [
    serviceBus_resource
  ]
}]
```

---

An alternate approach if you simply wanted to limit the creation;

You could decorate the `topics` parameter to limit the array length;

```
@maxLength(500)
param topics array
```

This would cause a deployment validation failure if you provided too many.

For a softer approach you could have another parameter for the max, verify by leveraging the ternary operator and then use a [loop index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/loops#integer-index);

```
param serviceBusName string
param topics array
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param maxTopics int = 3

resource serviceBus_resource  'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces@2021-11-01' = {
  name: serviceBusName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Premium'
    tier: 'Premium'
    capacity: 1
  }
}

var topicsToCreate = length(topics) > maxTopics ? maxTopics : length(topics)

resource serviceBus_topics 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics@2021-11-01' = [for i in range(0, topicsToCreate): {
  name: topics[i]
  parent: serviceBus_resource
}]
```

Comment: If the topics array had 1000 topics, would it just create the first 3, or would it break into chunks of 3 and create all the 1000 topics which it seems to be based on topicsToCreate? Ideally, I would want to create all 1000 topics. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very neat solution as i was going down powershell route and nested for loops.